# Fit 100 items in a circular container, evenly spaced with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, position, geometry

I have 100 items entering the viewport in random order. Together, they need to form a circle inside a DOM container. I need some way to calculate the position the items need to move to...

The structure is kinda like this:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/WvbKjb (visual sample with a bit of css and js inside)

```
<div id="circle"><!-- 100 items in here --></div</div>
```

And then the JS, for this sample, would generate 100 divs and set their position with css:

```
for (i = 0; i <= 100; i++) { 
    var item = document.createElement('div');
    item.id = 'item'+i;
    item.className = 'item';
    item.setAttribute('style', 'left:0px;top:0px');
    document.getElementById('circle').appendChild(item);
}
```

So I would generate 100 .item elements and move them around the screen. This movement is not an issue: what I don't know how to do is find the position each item has to end up at to properly fill the circle. Is there any way to easily calculate this with a formula? I'm afraid it's way beyond my math skills...

Thanks in advance for any help.

EDIT: using jQuery would be fine too.

Comment: Start with polar coordinates, then [convert them to coordinates on the Cartesian plane](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polar_coordinate_system#Converting_between_polar_and_Cartesian_coordinates).

Comment: First you must find a polygon that has 100 points and see how that fits in a circle. Then populate that polygon with javascript and then add the movement.

Answer (score 1):

You may start with this, just a bit of a math:
[Example](http://codepen.io/prowseed/pen/VLYBXV)

the main part is:

```
var spacing  = 360 / count;
var l = Math.cos(rotation * Math.PI / 180) * radius - itemRadius;
var t = Math.sin(rotation * Math.PI / 180) * radius - itemRadius;
rotation += spacing;
```

Where spacing is actually an angle

Comment: I want to completely fill the circle. I suppose I could use this method to keep making smaller circles till I get to the center. I'll give it a go :)

Answer (score 1):

Probably a little overloaded but this is what i tried and what worked for me: https://jsfiddle.net/tx7po9eg/1/

Main Part is this function which will calculate the position of a specific element depending on the defined center and the radius.

```
function getPos(cent, rad, amount, iteration) {
    var degree = 360 / amount * iteration;

    var changeY = cent.y - (Math.sin(degree * Math.PI / 180) * rad); 
    var changeX = cent.x - (Math.cos(degree * Math.PI / 180) * rad); 

    var ret = {};
    ret.x = Math.round(changeX * 100) / 100;
    ret.y = Math.round(changeY * 100) / 100;

    return ret;
}
```

here an example including visualization:
https://jsfiddle.net/tx7po9eg/3/

Answer (score 0):

You will have to decide exactly HOW you want to fit all the elements inside the circle. Do you want them in a single line around the parameter? At Random? Fill the circle?

If you want to fill the circle, one thing you could do is work like that - move from the center outside, starting by putting an item in the middle, then going out and putting another circle around it, then another around it, and like that keep wrapping it in layers until you hit the end of the circle. The only thing to figure out here would be the spacing (e.g. how many circles in each layer), and that would depend on the size of each element (are the sizes fixed)?

If you can make the container circle as large as you desire, you can just start making layers until you run out of items, and then place the big circle around them.

Hope this helps...

Comment: You're right. I should have clarified I want to fill the circle - your method makes sense. I will attempt that. The circle and the items are fixed in size so that should make it easier.